# Protegendo rotas no Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel

após fazer o login do usuário no sistema eu teoricamente teria que ter algumas rotas protegidas, como faço isso? No meu caso está retornando erro. Vejam:

routes.php

```
Route::group(['before' => 'auth'],function(){
    Route::controller('reserva','ReservaController');
});
```

Erro:

```
ErrorException
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class'Illuminate\Auth\Guard' does not have a method 'ClienteContato'
```

Para desencargo de consciência, meu model.

ClienteContato.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class ClienteContato extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
    protected $table        = 'cliente_contato';
    protected $primaryKey   = 'id_contato';
    protected $hidden       = array('password', 'remember_token');
    protected $fillable     = [...];
    public static $rules    = [];
    public $timestamps  = false;

    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->password;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tente remover o `__contruct` do seu model, ou passe um array `$attributes` : `public function __construct(array $attributes = array() { parent::__construct($attributes); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(Auth::check()){
    Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
        Route::get('/', array(
            'as' => 'home',
            'uses' => 'HomeController@index'// sua home do logado
        ));
    });
} else {
Route::get('/', array(
            'as' => 'home',
            'uses' => 'ContasController@getLogin'//sua tela de login
         ));
}﻿
```

Comment: É legal explicar *porquê* seu código resolve o problema. Confira o guia [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido.

Independente do nome da tabela que será usada para o login do usuário, a class `Auth` sempre terá um método `user()`, que permitirá o acesso às propriedades da tabela de login, que no meu caso é `cliente_contato`.

Então, ao invés de eu tentar o acesso por rota, posso simplesmente criar um filtro e chamar nos meus controllers protegidos, como vou mostrar abaixo:

```
Route::filter('logged', function(){
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

E em todos os meus controllers eu carrego no construtor o filtro da seguinte forma:

```
$this->beforeFilter('logged');
```

Vivendo e aprendendo. ;)

Comment: você pode marcar sua resposta como aceita, assim fica fácil para outros usuários identificar mais facilmente a solução encontrada para o problema da questão